# How to add a local file in JSfiddle?

Tags: html, jsfiddle

I did a Google search and couldn't find anything relevant to this topic. If I have a link

ex:

```
<a href="1.html">
```

in my HTML document then how to add `1.html` to **jsfiddle** so that it can provide a link to the file..??
I know there is an external file tab in JSfiddle button but I guess it is for URL. Mine is a local file. Any help would be much appreciated.

I also know that we can upload anything to JSfiddle. Then how can apply my link or what service like postimg.org can I use to link my external file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [orionhub.org](http://orionhub.org) to host your file, link to it from fiddle. On Orion, you'd have  to create the project, add file to it, make the file visible to the external world as part of that project. It's a bit convoluted at first, but makes sense and you'll get used to it.

Detailed steps for making certain resource publicly available via Orion:

1. Import/create a file
2. Select `View on Site` via `Open Related` menu

[image]

3. Add a site (if not exists) and copy the public link from View

[image]

UPDATE 2019/06/26 - codesandbox.io seems to allow file upload, but may not allow hotlinking to it. It might be time to move that altogether. (if the circumstances warrant, of course)

Comment: Orionhub cheat sheet. Create file. Right Click, Open Related, View on Site, (You may need to add a site). Add to site. ..... Then goto sites icon on LHS, (You may need to start the site), There is the URL and see it is now public. Test in another browser which is not logged in to OrionHub.

Comment: @Valamas, added you comment to answer, as I spent 15 minutes trying to get link myself before noticed it :)

Comment: Error "The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script"

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that jsfiddle allows you to upload additional html files -- only other resource files.  It also assumes working only with one of the four panes (HTML/CSS/JS).

Instead, you can use a site like Plunker which allows you to add different files of arbitrary types.  They will link together: http://plnkr.co/edit/NgdBXGkDDG1nOy47TaSK?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I prefer https://www.webpackbin.com. It's quite neutral in style, quick to load and you can also use it as anonymous user.

When you saved some code, you can share this code with others by handing over your link. When they now start modifying it, they'll effectively create their own version. Your version will stay the same and is still accessible on the same link.

Comment: The link to  https://www.webpackbin.com no longer exists.